# How to map XML to List of objects in ReactJS+Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, office-addins

There is a xml string, all I need to write a helper function to map this xml to list of object following below;

```
export interface WordItems {
  title: string;
  isOfficeInitialized: boolean;
  wSpacing: string;
  wFonts: string;
  wLang: string;
  wSz: number; // will get value from w:val element in xml string
}

const App: React.FC<WordItems> = () => {
  const parsedParagraph = helperParseFunction(XML_String);

  // Get run elements in this paragraph. "w:r" is the tagname for runs
  const runs = parsedParagraph.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("w:r");
  let textContent = "";
  // @ts-ignore
  runs.forEach((run) => (textContent += run.textContent));
  React.useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: 32 }}>
    ...
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default App;
```

XML string;

```
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14">
        <w:body>
          <w:p w:rsidR="006B7198" w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1" w:rsidRDefault="006B7198" w:rsidP="00A36BF1">
            <w:pPr>
              <w:spacing w:after="220" />
              <w:ind w:left="720" />
              <w:jc w:val="both" />
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>“</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:b />
                <w:spacing w:val="-2" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>Finance Agreements</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">” </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:spacing w:val="-2" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t xml:space="preserve">means </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00A36BF1">
              <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Malgun Gothic" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="en-GB" />
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>any loan or credit agreements, security agreements, shareholders undertakings and other related agreements and documents relating to the financing for the complete development and construction of the Project by financial institutions and/or other Third Parties for such amounts as may be agreed between the Company and the lenders;</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="006B7198" />
          <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00000000">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" />
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0" />
            <w:cols w:space="720" />
          </w:sectPr>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
```

what does helperParseFunction should be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries for converting an XML file to an Object, although You can write down your parser.

One of the best is [x2js](https://github.com/abdolence/x2js):

> This library provides XML to JSON (JavaScript Objects) and vice versa javascript conversion functions. The library is very small and has no dependencies.

You can also **check** the result with online convertor like [Code Beautify](https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson) and [convertJosn](https://www.convertjson.com/xml-to-json.htm)

Comment: Looks well, working on it, thanks